# How to remove trailing / on root route with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have several routes:

```
 www.example.com/rootRoute/flags
 www.example.com/rootRoute/test
 www.example.com/rootRoute/derp
```

For the route home page I would like my route to be:

```
 www.example.com/rootRoute
```

but react-router is forcing a / at the end so my root route is:

```
 www.example.com/rootRoute/
```

Any idea how to fix this?

```
 "react-router": "^4.3.1",
 "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
```

I've already set the path within my switch and route to the desired path but a / is always appended within the address bar.

```
 <Switch>
  <Route path={'/rootRoute/flags'} component={FeatureFlagsPage} />
  <Route path={'/rootRoute/test'} component={DerpComponent} />
  <Route path={'/rootRoute'} component={TestComponent} />
```

I expect there to be no / at the end of the root route.

Comment: can you show where you have the links to your components?

Comment: The links don't matter, there are Link components throughout the app, what matters is the /rootRoute adds a example.com/rootRoute/ and I want to rid myself of the trailing slash, I was able to do so by calling replaceState on window.history

Comment: hmm, do you mean that your app gets / automatically when you navigate? it seems the original demo does not have that problem https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config. I also did not experience that

Comment: yes it does, https://nw5y4q47pj.codesandbox.io/

Notice the / at the end? Go check your link again.

Comment: No, I did not. maybe you have some plugins that affected maybe. Can you try in incognito mode?

Comment: Open up this link: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config

move your eyes to the dark right center rectangle on your screen.  You will see https://nw5y4q47pj.codesandbox.io/

if you delete the trailing / it will be replaced when you hit enter.  Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: https://mo9jw228o9.codesandbox.io/ checkout my sandbox

Comment: sure that one works, why doesn't the embedded one work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191050/discussion-between-duc-mai-and-rami).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using history.replaceState('', 'State Title', 'Root Path');

in my index component.

Answer (score 1):

A few minor changes:

Move `/rootRoute` to the top and add exact to it. Get rid of the curly braces...

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/rootRoute' component={TestComponent} />
  <Route path='/rootRoute/flags' component={FeatureFlagsPage} />
  <Route path='/rootRoute/test' component={DerpComponent} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Will it remove the trailing /?

Comment: Yes, and this is the correct way of doing it in general... @Rami

Comment: Also, if it's the root route why not simply make it the root as in `<Route exact path='/' component={TestComponent} />` And the rest can be `<Route path='/flags' component={FeatureFlagsPage} />` etc...

Comment: Well you missed the question I think.  We have example.com/rootRoute/everyotherroute.  Now for the main homepage component I want the route to be www.example.com/rootRoute but currently it is example.com/rootRoute/

Comment: In any case... The solution above should solve the problem you were having... Here's the link to the docs - great documentation: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: hmm, I used the "a few minor changes" answer and it didn't solve my problem, / is still being added to /rootRoute/

Comment: also the { are there because I am calling a function to figure out the route.

Comment: if you see on the react router training website it even has a / at the end of the home page: https://codesandbox.io/s/yjzyzr29ov?from-embed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191044/discussion-between-rami-and-sakobu).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get rid of trailing slashes in URLs by adding a <Redirect />:

```
  <Switch>

    // put this rule before your Routes
    <Redirect from="/:url*(/+)" to={window.location.pathname.slice(0, -1)} />

    // and your Routes go here...

  </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a basename to the Router, like this:

```
<Router basename='/rootRoute'>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={ TestComponent }/>
    <Route path='/flags' component={ FeatureFlagsPage }/>
    <Route path='/test' component={ DerpComponent }/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```